# Filter objects based on a specific category name

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter all products whose category name is 'Books'. See below what I have tried but I'm getting an empty queryset.

Here is my `models.py` just in case:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

[...]      

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    [...]

class Category(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have tried this:

```
>>> from products.models import Product, Category
>>> c = Category(name='Books')
>>> c1 = Category(name='Textbooks', parent=c)
>>> c2 = Category(name='Primary school', parent=c1)
>>> p = Product(title='spam', description='spameggs', price=200, year=2018, category=c2)
>>> for x in (c, c1, c2, p):
...     x.save()
... 
>>> Product.objects.get(category=c2)
<Product: Product object (1)>
>>> Product.objects.filter(category__name='Books')
<QuerySet []>
>>> Product.objects.filter(Q(category__name='Books') | Q(category__parent__name='Books') | Q(category__parent__parent__name="Books"))
<QuerySet []>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the database with a database tool I realised that `Category` ForeignKey is `NULL`. The problem was that I was assigning the parents before the parents are saved, which meant that they had no PrimaryKey, so the ForeignKey gets set to `NULL`.